# How do i add an identity class in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hey guys i am a beginner when it comes to this therefore some help would be appreciated.

So i understand that ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduced new feature called Razor class libraries that lets you build views and pages as part of reusable library. ASP.NET Core Identity was moved to such RCL. You can override it in your project:

1. From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item.
2. From the left pane of the Add Scaffold dialog, select Identity > ADD.
3. In the ADD Identity dialog, choose files you wish to override.
   3.1 - Select layout if necessary
   3.2 - Select or create Data context class.
4. Hit ADD.

Now i don't really understand how this works and how to do it. I want to add the controllers that would be there like in .NET Core 2.0 such as the AccountController etc. I also want to add in the ApplicationUser.cs file that would've been in the Models folder in .NET Core 2.0

[Add Identity dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD2Sn.png)

I don't understand what to do here say if i wanted to add the other controllers such as AccountController.cs or ManageController.cs as well as ApplicationUser.cs

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I could reproduce yourissue that there is no `ApplicationUser` to select while adding scaffold items. I have submit an issue [Identity Library fail to choose the Data context class and User Class in Add Identity Window #8617](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8617). Templory, you could choose generate new context and user class, then replace them with your existing items. For Razor Identity Library, there are no `AccountController` any more, you could choose the files to generate and override the identity files in Add Scaffold Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the Razor class library is that the code is inside the library that is why you do not get the code in your project. The controllers are still there just they come from the library directly. Do you have a specific need to change them?

Read also the [official Microsoft docs about the change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.2#changes-to-authentication-code) where it is explained in detail.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply, so i am following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/9HNy4ZVG9IQ?t=207) , i moved my ApplicationDbContext.cs into the LamdaForums data project. The ApplicationDbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, now for me it just inherits from IdentityDbContext followed by nothing. Therefore to fix this i have to move the ApplicationUser.cs file into a new models folder in my LambdaForums.Data project however i can't find the ApplicationUser.cs file. I'm assuming it's stored in this RCL however i don't know how to bring it in.

Comment: The tutorial you do is for ASP.NET Core 2.0 where things are without the library. Now all this things are hidden inside the library and you just configure it. If you want to do it exactly like in the tutorial create a new project based on ASP.NET core 2.0 instead of 2.2 and I will be like that. Else you need to follow the [documentation for 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).